# Drag "page" animation

Tags: android

I'm working on an eBook reader for android. I have my content set up in a none scrollable webview. In order to turn page, i would like to create a kind of page/drag effect like shown here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd5f4nauKTE#t=1m8s

I've setted up a onTouchListener to my webview and added a cached image of it to a ImageView, and managed to drag it around wiht my finger, but i'm having trouble setting up animations on the way.

Here is my code so far:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgContentBitmap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgNext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPrev"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
    />

    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:id="@+id/webPageContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </android.webkit.WebView>
</FrameLayout>
```

And the activity:

```
public class TestPageActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private WebView webView;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView contentBitmap;
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
    private int pressedX;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.leftMargin = 0;
        params.topMargin = 0;

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webPageContent);

        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        ((FrameLayout)(webView.getParent())).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                int eventAction = event.getAction();
                int currentX = (int) event.getX();

                Log.d("main", "current x = "+currentX);
                Log.d("main", "pressed x = "+pressedX);

                switch(eventAction){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("main", "down");
                        pressedX = (int) event.getX();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.d("main", "move");
                        params.leftMargin = (pressedX-currentX);
                        contentBitmap.setLayoutParams(params);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("main", "up");
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadData(getString(R.string.lorem_ipsum), "text/html", "utf-8");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            }
        });

        webView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture){
                webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                webView.layout(0, 0, webView.getWidth(), webView.getBottom());
                webView.buildDrawingCache(true);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache());
                webView.setVisibility(WebView.INVISIBLE);

                webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                contentBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                webView.setPictureListener(null);

            }
        });

        contentBitmap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgContentBitmap);
        /*

        contentBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an solution?
Otherwise I would say, you can set an Fragment as the view and use the FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction to place the view in the Activity.
Afterwards you can add an Animation to the Transaction with: setCustomAnimation(R.anim.New_in, R.anim.Old_out, R.anim.Old_in, R.anim.New_out);